# How to delay the execution of a syncAdapter with requestSync

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-syncadapter

Google recommend delaying the execution of a syncAdapter when receiving GCM push notification:

> Note: If you use GCM to trigger your sync adapter via a broadcast to
>   all devices where your app is installed, remember that they receive
>   your message at roughly the same time. This situation can cause
>   multiple instance of your sync adapter to run at the same time,
>   causing server and network overload. To avoid this situation for a
>   broadcast to all devices, you should consider deferring the start of
>   the sync adapter for a period that's unique for each device. ([source](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html))

However, I could not find a way to issue a SyncRequest with a delay parameter ([API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#requestSync(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle))). The only other (pretty hacky) alternative I can think of is to start a service (which will have to hold the wake up lock, since it is a broadcast receiver of a push notification) which sleeps a couple of seconds, issues a SyncRequest, and releases the wake up lock. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a handler.

```
static final long c_delayMax = 120 * 1000;
static Random r = new Random();

public static void delayedNotification(Bundle data) {
    Handler h = new Handler();
    long delay = r.nextLong() % c_delayMax;
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() { makeSyncRequest(data); }
    }, delay);
}
```